# Relative importing and module reloading

Tags: python, python-import, sys

I have a machine learning project and I have to conduct m.l. experiments. Each experiment is made with a module that is strongly dependent on other files in the repository. For the sake of reproducibility, I consider each experiment as a snapshot of the repository. So later I want to reproduce the experiment and compare it to another experiment in ONE script. To do this I restore the state of the repository at the moment of the experiment in special folder `reproduce/experiment_name` and organize the following structure:

```
├── launcher.py
├── package
│   ├── dependency.py
│   └── subpackage
│       └── module.py
└── reproduce
    ├── experiment_23
    │   └── package
    │       ├── dependency.py
    │       └── subpackage
    │           ├── module.py
    └── experiment_24
        └── package
            ├── dependency.py
            └── subpackage
                └── module.py
```

So in `launcher.py` I want to import the content of `experiment_23` given the path to the needed module with `importlib.utils`. But I need to keep it's dependencies so that old code works in its own realm. I come up with an idea to modify the `sys.path` and add path right before the import and then remove it. Here is the content of `launcher.py`.

```
import sys
import importlib.util


path_to_module = "/package/subpackage/module.py"
experiment_path = "/reproduce/exp23"
project_path = "/home/user/PycharmProjects/PathTest"

# Here I add path to experiment directory
sys.path.insert(0, project_path + experiment_path)

spec = importlib.util.spec_from_file_location("", project_path + experiment_path + path_to_module, )
exp23 = importlib.util.module_from_spec(spec)
spec.loader.exec_module(exp23)

# Clear path
sys.path = sys.path[1:]
# This runs successfully
exp23.run()


# So now i want to import my newest version of the module.py
# And this fails, meaning it executes code from exp23
import package.subpackage.module as exp
exp.run()
```

Content of `module.py`

```
from package.dependency import function


def run():
    function()
```

and `dependency.py` is a success marker:

```
def function():
    print("23")
```

So the problem is that once the import was made and dependency loaded `from package.dependency import function`, python will no longer look for it in `sys.path` and use some kind of cache. My question is how can I avoid usage of cache in this case or at least how can I achieve similar functionality with different methods?

Comment: why not use `from reproduce.experiment_24.import package as pkg` and then use `function = pkg.dependancy.function` ?

Comment: @sahasrara62, I'm not sure if you have meant this, but i use `from package.dependency import function` in current code and in "history" code as a dependency, meaning that i do not import it explicilty. It is being imported by other `module.py`, in which i'm interested.

Comment: please [go through this](https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/import.html) , try to import this way, it' not explict, but  is right way to do so

Comment: You may want to [read this](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So before anything else, I'll assume you have an `__init__.py` inside every `package` and `subpackage` directory to make them actual "packages"; as specified [here](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#regular-packages).

Now, you should notice how `subpackage` containing `module.py` is an actual sub-package of `package`. So when you do `from package.dependency import ...`, you are trying to import from the parent package. Not only is this a bad practice, but the path that you use in `launcher.py` only-and-directly targets `module.py`, which has no idea what `package` is, or even `subpackage` for that matter.

What you should be targeting is `package`, which (again, assuming you have an `__init__.py` in there) will load as an actual "package". Making everything inside it properly accessible... after a few adjustments.

In your `__init__.py`'s you should expose everything you want this module to contain. For example, in your `package/__init__.py` you should have the line `from . import subpackage`. This will not only allow you to do stuff like `package.subpackage`, and it's also vital in loading the contents of `subpackage`.

Following the same logic, in your `subpackage/__init__.py` there should be `from . import module`, loading and exposing `module.py`, allowing you to do `package.subpackage.module`.

This should be all you'd need to properly load and access all your desired contents... except you also wrap all of that in `experiment_n` folders. Here you have two options: You can make `experiment_n` a package with an `__init__.py`, expose its `package` and target that with `importlib`, or you could rename `package` to `experiment_n` and delete the top folder. Going from this:

```
experiment_23
    └── package
        ├── __init__.py
        ├── dependency.py
        └── subpackage
            ├── __init__.py
            └── module.py
```

To this:

```
experiment_23
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── dependency.py
    └── subpackage
        ├── __init__.py
        └── module.py
```

Let's take a break from folder editing and check out how you'd use our current iteration in code. Consider the following `launcher.py`:

```
import sys, os
import importlib.util

current_directory = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))

path_to_experiment = os.path.join(current_directory, 'reproduce/experiment_23')

path_to_experiment = os.path.join(path_to_experiment, '__init__.py') # package!

spec = importlib.util.spec_from_file_location('exp23', path_to_experiment, submodule_search_locations = [])

exp23 = importlib.util.module_from_spec(spec)

sys.modules[exp23.__name__] = exp23

# old one
spec.loader.exec_module(exp23)

exp23.subpackage.module.run()

# new one
import package.subpackage.module as exp

exp.run()
```

With the main function printing `main` and the reproduce one printing `exp23`.

First, we compose our `path_to_experiment`, pointing to our package's `__init__.py`. `module_from_file_location` needs a **file**, not a folder, hence why we don't target `/expriment_23` directly. After, with an actual name (`exp23`), we get our `spec` with `spec_from_file_location`, setting `submodule_search_locations` to an empty list to indicate it's a package as specified [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/importlib/_bootstrap_external.py#L639). Last, fetch our module with `module_from_spec`.

It's important that we add our new module to `sys.modules` so relative imports (which we use) can find their parent module.

We let our module execute and call its and our new module's `run` function:

```
main
main
```

Seems like it didn't work, we wanted the first one to be `exp23`

The culprit is this `from package.dependency import function` line in our `experiment_23/subpackage/module.py`. The import here is `absolute`, not `relative`, meaning it will look for / or import `"package"` in / to `sys.modules` and use that. In this case, this points directly to our main package. Changing it to `from ..dependency import function` and re-running `launcher.py` gives us:

```
exp23
main
```

Success :)

The import system can be pretty confusing, spending some time with the [import system docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html) and [importlib docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html) will save you a lot of headache when a similar situation arrises.

As an optional suggestion, you can move `module.py` in `experiment_23` and out of `subpackage` and delete `subpackage`. Now you can do `from .dependency import function`. Some would argue that doing super relative imports (using more than one `.`) is bad practice or at least shows insufficient understanding of package structuring.

Edit: All changes applied to `experiment_23` are respective to the main experiment's package and every other `experiment_n`...